# Generic RenderFragment not allowing parameters

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I create a component PopupForm which take `PopupFormAvatar` component as parameter

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment PopupFormAvatar { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

PopupFormAvatar also takes multiple parameters.

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

I want to use it like this

```
<PopupForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit" Setting="popupFormSettings">

  <PopupFormAvatar Text="asdad">
      <CustomerImage></CustomerImage> // as ChildContent
  </PopupFormAvatar>

  <ChildContent>
     Other content goes here
  </ChildContent>
 </PopupForm>
```

It throws the error `Unrecognized attribute Text on child content element PopupFormAvatar`

if in my popup component if I only take one parameter as `ChildContent` it works, but I want `PopupFormAvatar` and `other content` separately

```
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } // instead of PopupFormAvatar
```

or put it inside ChildContent

```
<PopupForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit" Setting="popupFormSettings">

  <ChildContent>
     <PopupFormAvatar Text="asdad">
         <CustomerImage></CustomerImage> // as ChildContent
      </PopupFormAvatar>
  </ChildContent>
  

 </PopupForm>
```

Comment: "I want to use it like this" -  you can't do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Your main point of confusion is understandable: the problem is that when you use syntax like `<PopupFormAvatar>` it's ambiguous in certain contexts.  In your case, you are trying to use an element name (`PopupFormAvatar`) to refer to a *property*.  So you're telling `PopupForm` that for the property named `PopupFormAvatar` use this particular fragment.  This is represented by the following code:

```
<PopupFormAvatar Text="asdad">
    <CustomerImage></CustomerImage> // as ChildContent
</PopupFormAvatar>
```

Here's the problem: while most of the time in Blazor, the syntax `<PopupFormAvatar>` would refer to a *component*, in this case it does *not* refer to a component.  It refers to a property of `PopupForm`, which declares the `PopupFormAvatar` property as a render fragment.  This means that you have literally not done anything with your actual `PopupFormAvatar` component here -- the fact that component exists is completely irrelevant; the name `PopupFormAvatar` is simply the name of the property and the fact that it also matches a component is an unhappy coincidence.

This is why you get the error, `Unrecognized attribute Text on child content element PopupFormAvatar`. Because that attribute is only recognized for the *component* -- which has not been enlisted.

To make this work, you simply have to recognize all of that and supply the actual component:

```
<PopupFormAvatar>
    <PopupFormAvatar Text="Hello World">
        asdfasdfas
    </PopupFormAvatar>
</PopupFormAvatar>
```

Note the duplication of `PopupFormAvatar` as an element. The first is slotting in for the property.  The latter is providing the actual content.  This is why the `Text` attribute can be assigned -- the nested version is actually using your Blazor component (as opposed to referring to the property).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have used it like you are saying and it works, it would have been great if we can take input as a specific component, there is an issue open on blazor repository i hope this feature get implemented soon. (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29379)